# change permissions for files and directories under home directory

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I share a Linux server with several people. Is it better to change the permissions of files and directories under my home? I wonder if other or group users will have access to or even modify my files.

Except `~/public_html`, is it all right to change the permissions of all the other files and directories including hidden ones to be unreadable, unwritable and unexecutable for other and group users?

I find some directories under my home has permission like this `drwsrws---`. I saw somewhere online that the `s` is the `set-UID` or `set-groupID` flag. But What does `s` mean actually for the group users? Is it safe to drop it?

Comment: btw, this should probably be on serverfault.com

Comment: you mean superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should change files/folders that you don't want read by others like this:

```
chmod go-rwx SECRET_FILE_OR_FOLDER
```

(this makes it unable to be read, written or  by anyone else.)

You should also make sure you have the right modes on your home directory, eg,

```
chmod go-w ~
```

Comment: If necessary, you can also do something like this.  <code>-R</code> means recursive.  <code>chmod -R go-rwx $HOME</code>  This will do the same as Peter's suggestion while at the same time stripping non-owner rights from ALL files in your home directory.